# How to oblige a class' users to use it off the UI thread in Android?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

How to oblige a class' users to use it off the UI thread in Android?
I know its a bad practice to require client instead of server to do this, but in this case it's necessary.

So can I check if a class' constructor or a method is called from the main thread and throw an exception?

Also, how do I document it or use naming conventions in a way that will imply it should not be used in the main thread?

The class is meant to be plugged in different kinds of asynchronous implementations - sometimes a service is using it and sometimes an async task is using it in its doInBackground() method

Not that it matters, but here is my class:

```
/**
 * Do not run this on the UI Thread!
 * 
 * @author me
 * 
 */
public class LogInUserOnServerSynchronous {

    private Context context;

    private JSONParser jsonParser;
    private OnLogInUserOnServerListener listener;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String deviceId;
    private HashMap<String, String> stringData;

    private String error = "";
    private boolean initialLogin;

    public LogInUserOnServerSynchronous(//
            HashMap<String, String> stringData, //
            JSONParser jsonParser, //
            Context context, //
            OnLogInUserOnServerListener listener, //
            String email, //
            String password, //
            String deviceId, //
            boolean initialLogin) {
        this.jsonParser = jsonParser;
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
        this.stringData = stringData;
        this.initialLogin = initialLogin;
        login();
    } // End of Constructor

    private void login() {

        // do some networking here
            if (listener != null) {
                if (registrationDataModel != null) {
                    listener.onLogInUserOnServerSuccess(registrationDataModel);
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            error = "An error occurred";
            e.printStackTrace();
            communicateFailure();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            error = "An error occurred";
            communicateFailure();
        }
    } // End of login

    private void communicateFailure() {
        if (error != null && error.contentEquals("You are already logged in")) {
            error = "";
        }
        listener.onLogInUserOnServerFailure(error);
    }

} // End of Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this construction to check if method is executed on the MainThread or not.

```
if(Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
   // Current Thread is Main Thread.
    throw new IllegalStateException("Please call this method asynchroniously!");
}
```

**Edit.** Also add `javadoc` to notify a developer and also you can add `throws` signature to the method declaration in order to show a developer that there can be exception.

Comment: Thank you! And how about ways to document or imply that the class should be run off the main thread?

Comment: I edited. Add javadoc and trows to the constructor signature. It should be enough